# Failed to call API on app server from client browser

Tags: deployment, .net-6.0, hosting, angular16

My Angular 16 application is hosted on a web server and .NET 6 API is hosted on an app server. When I call from web server browser the api calls resolves successfully but when I call from any client browser other than web server it fails to resolve the call. what are the possible resons to block this call ??

I tried with allow CORS to all domain request but doesn't work